# Opacity Properity in IE6

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6, opacity

I have been working on this for a little while, and I have also searched stackoverflow, but couldn't find an answer.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 950px;
    opacity: .5;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 50);
    background: #fff;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    -moz-opacity: 0.5;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

But it doesn't work for me in using IETester.
The other versions display it correctly, IE6 does not.

So, where is the bug?
What have I missed ?

Comment: Did you actually test this directly on IE6?  Or did you just simulate it with IETester?

Comment: actually i have just copy the code and paste it here....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For IE 6 and 7, try the following:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50);
```

[Source](http://robertnyman.com/2008/09/16/you-want-css-opacity-to-go-with-that-well-suit-yourself/).

Comment: it‘still do not work......but really thank you...i mean i really began consider about there is problem with my IEtester....